# Form Load ComboBox DropDownList

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, drop-down-menu, load

what I'm trying to do is when program start to auto select value 0 or 1 from combobox1

ComboBox DropDownList:
- Yes - ( Value 0 )
- No - ( Value 1 )

I try something like this, but didnt work

```
// ------------------- StartUP Load
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 comboBox4.SelectionStart = 0;
}
```

Comment: [List of freely available programming books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
comboBox4.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

That should start it at Yes. If you want to start it at No then use

```
comboBox4.SelectedIndex = 1;
```